# Cannot display data in xhtml DataTable by using Hibernate, Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, primefaces

I'm doing some test to display data. I want users to see  data of other users after singing up + seeing his/her own username. So basically the application proceeds with saving a user to a database and displaying his own username in another form. This second form cannot display other usernames in a table. I have no idea what to do. Shall I somehow implement this method in a try/catch block?

Generic Dao Interface:

```
package com.example.j2eeapp.dao;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

public interface Dao <T, ID extends Serializable> {
  T save (T entity);
  List<T> findAll();
  void flush();
}
```

Dao Implementation:

```
package com.example.j2eeapp.dao;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.example.j2eeapp.test.BasicView;

@Component
@Transactional
public abstract class DaoImpl <T, ID extends Serializable> implements Dao<T,ID> {

private Class<T> persistentClass;

private EntityManager entityManager;

public DaoImpl(Class<T> persistentClass) {
    this.persistentClass = persistentClass;
}

protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return entityManager;
}

@PersistenceContext
public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}

public Class<T> getPersistentClass() {
    return persistentClass;
}

public T save(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    return entity;
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<T> findAll() {
    return getEntityManager()
        .createQuery("from " + getPersistentClass().getSimpleName() )
        .getResultList();
}

}
public void flush() {
    getEntityManager().flush();
}



public List<T> getfindUserName(){
    return findUserName();
}

}
```

xhtml form:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
   <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    template="/WEB-INF/templates/general.xhtml">

<ui:define name="title"><h:outputText value="Success" /></ui:define>
<ui:define name="header"><h:outputText value="Success" /></ui:define>

<ui:define name="content">
    <h:form id="successForm">
        <p:fieldset styleClass="fieldset" legend="Succcess">


 <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="5">

    <h:outputText id="display" value="#{basicView.userName}" />

        <p:dataTable var="usersDetails" value="#{daoImpl.findAll}">
        <p:column headerText="Id">
          <h:outputText value="#{usersDetails.id}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="User Name">
          <h:outputText value="#{usersDetails.userName}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Password">
          <h:outputText value="#{usersDetails.password}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Last name">
          <h:outputText value="#{usersDetails.lastName}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="First name">
          <h:outputText value="#{usersDetails.firstName}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:panelGrid>
        </p:fieldset>
    </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

without checking the code in depth, I assume that your datatable definition is wrong.

```
<p:dataTable var="usersDetails" value="#{daoImpl.findUserName}">
    <p:column headerText="Id">
      <h:outputText value="#{userDetails.userId}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="User Nmae">
      <h:outputText value="#{userDetails.userName}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Password">
      <h:outputText value="" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Last name">
      <h:outputText value="" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="First name">
      <h:outputText value="" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Where `#{daoImpl.findUserName}` should actually return the user entity.

Best

**Update based on comment**

*No Records found* basically means, that your backing bean was called but didn't return any entities to display.

So either you didn't persist any `userDetails` at the point of time of loading your table, or you didn't update the data in your table.

Since you are using primefaces [I recommend you to take a look at the showcases they provide.](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/basic.xhtml)

What I also saw is, that your datatable doesn't have an ID, which might cause troubles:

```
<p:dataTable id="userDataTable" var="usersDetails" value="#{daoImpl.findUserName}">
    <p:column headerText="Id">
      <h:outputText value="#{userDetails.userId}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="User Nmae">
      <h:outputText value="#{userDetails.userName}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Password">
      <h:outputText value="" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Last name">
      <h:outputText value="" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="First name">
      <h:outputText value="" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer. I did what You wrote, but now table displays only "no records found" and again there is nothing relevant in logs ( no error message). I edited my question. Can You please advice something. Regards.